# enum vs. class loaders

Tags: java, enums

Sometimes you may even not know that the environment you plug you code in has more than one class loader. May I still expect that operation "==" will work on enum values in this case?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

`"=="` will not work, but you want to use `.equals()` anyway.

You might be interested in the apache commons lang class: [link text](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/enums/Enum.html)

Comment: BTW, implementation of Enum `equals()` just calls `this==other` (Sun/Oracle JDK 6).

Comment: yup, as I just wrote in my own answer

Comment: This might be true for this release. However, following the language semantics, `==` will never be valid while `.equals()` might(!) work. See also the apache-commons Enum implemenation.

Comment: I know about the important distinction between == and equals(). But enum intentionally violates this distinction and that's not likely to change. Although I agree that equals is a better choice semantically

Answer (score 13):

Multiple classloaders may not be the problem, as long as the enum is only available through one of them. If that is not the case, you lose all the benefits of an enum.

And by the way, using `equals()` doesn't help either. Here's the implementation of `Enum.equals(Object)` in Java 1.6:

```
public final boolean equals(Object other) { 
    return this==other;
}
```

Comment: Same thing here as on josefx's post; it can still work when an enum is loaded by multiple class loaders, you just have to be careful that they are isolated from each other.

Comment: Sure, but it's a pain. It breaks any assumption one tends to make about enums. And it breaks the enum singleton pattern.

Comment: Classloaders break all singleton patterns.

Answer (score 10):

**If your enum class is only loaded once it will still work.**

- your enum is only used within the loaded plugin
- the enum has been loaded by a parent classloader of the individual plugin classloaders

**If your enum class is loaded by different classloaders it will not work**

- you pass the enum values between different plugins but the application classloader has not loaded the enum. (it can still work if the enum values never cross between plugins)

**The reason why it is this way**

Java uses object instances to represent the different enum values, each of these instances is stored as a static field within the enum class. If the enum is loaded twice each enum value is represented by two different object instances. The `== operator` only compares the references and is unaware of the multiple instances representing an enum value, so it will fail to match values loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: "The == operator only compares the references" sounds a little bit like a dogma. Enum is already a pretty special thing. One more speciality could be defining "==" as "this.ordinal() == that.ordinal()". Could that solve the issue?

Comment: @Dima as long as both loaded definitions of the enum are identical it will work. The ordinal value only contains the index (position) of the Enum constant in the source code, if the code changes (new values, different ordering) it would still break. If speed is not an issue you can compare their names.