# Issues running obfuscated DEX modules - AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, reflection, proguard, obfuscation, dex

I'm developing an Android application based on a main APK installed on the mobile device, and some android modules that are compiled to a .dex file. These files are loaded at runtime by the main application and the classes inside the .dex files are instantiated via Dynamic Dex Loading.

I'm facing some issues related to proguard, as even if I use the **@Keep annotation** on exposed methods in the modules and the main APK and I tell to proguard to **keep interfaces methods**, when I call one of the methods implemented in a module i get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.myproject, PID: 13893
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "z.a com.android.myproject.MyClass.mymethod()"
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.H(:784)
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.M(:258)
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.a0(:198)
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.U(:148)
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.C(:133)
    at com.android.myproject.MainService.onServiceConnected(:90)...
```

If i try to debug, and i place a breakpoint right on the method call, using the "Evaluate Expression" tool in Android Studio I'm able to call the method with success, but if I let it execute on its own it crashes with the previous exception.

Can someone help me please? Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you think that minifier (Proguard/R8) is the culprit here? Does the call succeed when you set `minifyEnabled` to `false`?

Comment: Of course with minifyEnabled to false everything works perfectly. I think that there's something linked to obfuscation that mess things up, but still can't figure what's the cause...

Comment: I'd first suggest to verify that the class/method were named as you'd expect by inspecting the dex's bytecode (both module's and main app's). You've mentioned that the method is being called successfully with debugger attached and fails when it doesn't - the only thing that comes to my mind which might explain this behavior is the fact that with debugger attached the bytecode is being executed in interpreter mode. Can you post a minimal example (the interface + invoking code from main app; the interface + implementation class from the module dex)?

Comment: COMMENT-PART-1: I've been able to solve the problem explained in the issue by adding some other keep options in my proguard file. Anyway, another problem appears. I try to Describe you the code at my best:

- In the main APK: my main thread start its execution, loads the .dex module via InMemoryDexClassLoader. As a result i get an Object of type "MyType", where "MyType" is an interface that every .dex module implements.
This interface contains the "myMethod()" method, which return a value defined in "MyEnum".

- "MyEnum" and "MyType" are both in APK and in the .dex module.

Comment: COMMENT-PART-2:

- Once the Object is loaded, I call `object.myMethod()` expecting to receive a particular value of "MyEnum" as implemented in the dynamically loaded object but i get the following exception:

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.core, PID: 18442
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field ENUM_VALUE of type Lcom/android/enums/MyEnum; in class Lcom/android/enums/MyEnum; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.android.enums.MyEnum' appears in /data/app/com.android.myproject-5WnEEtImTdcatJ_yyLms3A==/base.apk)
...`

Comment: COMMENT-PART-3:
Using the debugger **i noticed that the implementation of "myMethod()" in the .dex module seems to refer to the "MyEnum" in the main APK instead of "MyEnum" inside the .dex module.** I double checked import
statements and they are correct. Do you have any suggest? Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you've resolved your original issue - please either answer it or close it. As to your second issue - note that you're trying to share an enum between class loaders, which might not work as you'd expect (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4287630/1233652)). Therefore consider to use plain integer consts instead. If you have further questions regarding that - I'd suggest you to ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @MarioDelloVicario Have you resolved this problem? I am struggling with the similar case. One difference: instead of enum, I am facing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method` for a static function that should return object from runtime loaded dex.

Comment: I didn't manage to solve the problem, I'm sorry. I just wrote my own custom obfuscator and continued using it instead of proguard